# How to assign a custom object to bytesArray? As3

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

I have a TActor class and a function to_bytes() inside it that should compress it to a bytes array as in this example: http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1642

```
 public function to_bytes():ByteArray
 {
        registerClassAlias("TActor",TActor);
        var bytes:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
        bytes.writeObject(this as TActor);
        bytes.position=0;
        trace(bytes.readObject());
        bytes.position=0;
        trace(bytes.readObject() as TActor);

        return bytes;
}
```

However, the first trace prints undefined and the second one null instead of [object TActor].
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that the `this` keyword returns the current instance of the object. What you are currently doing is attempting to pass the `this` instance to `writeObject`, which will only work if there is an instance of `TActor` instantiated. So it would work in this scenario:

In some class where you instantiate TActor:

```
var tactor:TActor = new TActor();
tactor.to_bytes();
```

Then it should serialize correctly.

Also as we discovered in the comments, `TActor` is of type `MovieClip`, currently you cannot use `writeObject()` on Objects of type `MovieClip`. More specifically any object that is a dynamic class cannot be used in writeObject. Changing it to `Sprite` solved this particular case.

Comment: I wrote this in a class where a TActor reference, player, had been created (with new TActor()) `var bytes:ByteArray=player.to_bytes();
    bytes.position=0;
    trace("Player:",bytes.readObject() as TActor);` The result is Player: null. Was it the thing that you meant?

Comment: Can you post the exact code you used to implement it with your player object? This should work perfectly fine, but I'll test it just to verify.

Comment: Tested and verified on my end, this should be correct. So I'm assuming it's how your player is created, or something with your hierarchy.

Comment: To start to_bytes() you should hit spacebar

Comment: The processing is in TMain get_key_down

Comment: The problem is you cannot writeObject on type MovieClip. Change TActor in your fla to use baseclass flash.display.Sprite. Then have it extend Sprite in your TActor.as that will solve the problem.